# Where can I find the list of arguments for chrome and internet explorer?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, preferences, selenium-firefoxdriver, chrome-options

Where can I find the list of arguments for chrome and internet explorer? Just like in Mozilla , we use 'about:config' for list of preferences. Is there any command to invoke in chrome browser to get thislist/

**EDIT -I**

options.addArguments("**disable-popup-blocking**", "true");
    options.addArguments("**download.default_director**y","../Gmail/TestData/DownloadedFiles");
    options.addArguments("**download.directory_upgrade**", "true");
    options.addArguments("**download.prompt_for_download**", "false");

Here i want the list of these arguments

Answer (score 0):

For Internet explorer you can find them on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025(v=vs.85).aspx).

And for Chrome, on Peter Beverloo's blog [here](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

Comment: I thin u did not get my question. I want to use the references in seleinum for automation.

Comment: In case you should have also specifies that you don't know how to use them in Selenium. Both Chrome and Internet Explorer have the Options class, ChromeOptions and InternetExplorerOptions. You create an object from it and call the AddArgument method using the browser arguments that you desire.

Comment: Thanks,  I am aware to create Options class object. Here i want the list of arguments to be passed into the options.addArguments("...") statement

just like options.addArguments("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
  options.addArguments("download.default_directory","../Gmail/TestData/DownloadedFiles");
  options.addArguments("download.directory_upgrade", "true");
  options.addArguments("download.prompt_for_download", "false");

Comment: And exactly those are present in the links that I gave you in the answer.

Comment: I could not find any of the above mentioned arguments in your link :(  except popup blocking